# GitLab CI: How to setup postgres image using GitLab secure variables

Tags: postgresql, continuous-integration, environment-variables, gitlab, environment

This is a part of my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: ruby:2.3.1

services:
  - postgres:latest
  - mysql:latest
...
variables:
  MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "1"
...
```

All postgres variables

- POSTGRES_DB
- POSTGRES_USER
- POSTGRES_PASSWORD

are specified as GitLab secure variables. But when the pipeline runs I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "runner" does not exist
```

If I set these variables through `variables` section in .gitlab-ci.yml everything works just fine.

So it seems like these variables when set through GitLab secure variables are not set properly and postgres image doesn't use them.

My goal is to remove postgres db name, user and password from `variables` section in .gitlab-ci.yml.

Please help, thanks in advance.

PS: I use docker executor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not one to revive dead threads... but I spent a couple of hours on this issue myself and figure someone else might benefit...  Turns out it was simple.

Gitlab-CI doesn't like a blank username, so I had to explicitly set it:

> gitlab-ci.yml

```
services:
  - postgres:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: test
  POSTGRES_USER: user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
```

> config/database.yml

```
test:
  host: postgres
  user: user
  database: test
```